# no response when execute .sh file by double click on fedora20

Tags: intellij-idea, fedora

Today,I installed fedora20 on my computer and then downloaded the Intellij idea13, but when I execute the file by double clicking, there is no response. But it works well in a terminal with ./idea.sh.

Thanks, I need your help!

Comment: have you  ran the command chmod +x idea.sh  to make your file executable

Comment: yeah,the file's permission is 755.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fedora user but the following may help you to understand the problem.

When you double-click an item from the file manager, the default application for that type of file is loaded.

That depends on the configuration for the specific MIME type (which is `application/x-sh`).

There's a big chance that the default application for `.sh` files is set to `gedit` or `kwrite` depending on the desktop environment. The Intellij Idea installer is binary file and maybe the application is failing to load.

Have you tried right-clicking the file and select the option 'Open in Terminal'? The context menu may also show something like `Execute` or `Launch`.

Comment: thanks for your answer.I am already right-clicking the file and select      the option 'open with', and select the 'startup software'.There is also no response.